# Blender can no longer navigate 3D view or move objects on grid in Windows 10

Tags: windows

When moving around and rotating in Blender, I used to hold the middle mouse button (MM), but after upgrading to Windows 10, the OS overrides Blender's functionality and instead, it opens some weird "here's an overview of your open windows"-view.

The same problem occurs when I want to move an object along a certain axis.  I used to lock on a grid using the MM.

Is there a way to make the MM behave as it did previously?

Comment: or a general search for on your favourite search engine for ' help windows 10 has taken over my keyboard shortcuts '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Windows 10, but it is possible avoid MM. For rotating the 3D view, you can go to User Preferences > Input > Emulate middle mouse button. After this, you can rotate the view by pressing alt + left mouse button. For constraining to axis, you can simply type the name of the axis. For example "move on the X axis" would be G followed by X. If you want to exclude one axis from a motion, use shift ("move on all axes except X"would be G followed by Shift + X). This applies also to rotation and scaling.